# How to use EventBus in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, event-bus

In my application i use `fragment` into `Activity` and i want when run one code into `fragment`, call some codes in `Activity`.

I write below codes but when load data not run `activity` code.!

**Fragment codes:**

```
    public void loadRecentPosts() {
        ApiUtils.getApiInterface().getRecentPosts(AppConstant.DEFAULT_PAGE).enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    if (!recentPostList.isEmpty()) {
                        recentPostList.clear();
                    }
                    recentPostList.addAll(response.body());
                    if (recentPostList.size() > 0) {
                        recentPostAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(new LoadMainDataEvent());
                    }
                } else {
                    showEmptyView();
                }
                pbSectionLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {
                showEmptyView();
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Activity code:**

```
@Subscribe (threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onLoadMainDataEvent(LoadMainDataEvent loadMainDataEvent){
    Toast.makeText(activity, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I want when get data from server into `fragment`, run codes in `activity` page.

How can i fix it? please help me. Thanks

Comment: Have you register `EventBus` in `Activity`?

Comment: @KishoreJethava, how can i it? can you help me? please

Comment: Add this in your `onStart()` method of your fragment -  `EventBus.getDefault().register(this);`

Comment: follow official [documents](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus#eventbus-in-3-steps)

Comment: @GaneshKalal, thanks my bro. it's ok and work me

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it work fine**

FragmentClass.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
     }
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(MessageBusEvent event) {
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
        //unregister event bus
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onDestroy();
}
```